# Eigenvalue of multiplication in a number field.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraic number field. $b \in \mathbb{K}$ defines a linear transformation $\phi(b)$ on $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}$ by multiplication - $\phi(b)(x):=bx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{K}$. One way to calculate the eigenvalues of this matrix is by taking a suitable basis for $\mathbb{K}$ and calculating the determinant. This gives us that the eigenvalues are the conjugates of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there some non computational way of proving this fact, maybe even showing what the eigenvectors should be?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474611/68188) answer does refer to something like what I am asking for, unfortunately I do not really understand it.

Comment: You should specify that you're looking for the eigenvalues and matrix of $\phi$ **over** $\Bbb Q$.  The default assumption would be that you're considering this over $\Bbb K$.

Comment: Also, what is it that you want to prove?  That the eigenvalues of a matrix match the eigenvalues of the transformation, regardless of one's choice of basis?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I want to prove that the eigenvalue is b without actually computing the matrix/characteristic polynomial. Some abstract argument that "explains" why this should be expected to happen.

Comment: ...That's not what I meant by "over".  At any rate, let me know if my answer is to your liking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an argument you might like:

Since $\phi = \phi(b)$ is a linear map on a $\Bbb Q$ vector space, its [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29) $m(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ (i.e. $m \in \Bbb Q[x]$).  Note that the $\Bbb K$-eigenvalues of $\phi$ are precisely the roots of $m(x)$ in $\Bbb K$ (not necessarily up to multiplicity).

Now, because $\Bbb K$ is algebraic, there exists a (monic) polynomial $p \in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that $p(x) = 0$ iff $x$ is conjugate to $b$ (that is, we take $p$ to be the [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28field_theory%29) of $b$).  Because $p(b) = 0$, we may conclude that $p(\phi) = 0$.  Thus, $m(x) \mid p(x)$.  Because $p$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, we may conclude that $m(x) = p(x)$

Note, however, that the degree of $m$ is equal to the dimension of $\Bbb K$ as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space.  Since $m$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$ and because $\phi$ has the same degree, we conclude that $m$ **is** the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$.

Thus, the eigenvalues of $\phi$ are precisely the conjugates of $b$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Your proof is nice but if you looked at the answer I linked, the poster mentions some stuff towards the end of his answer using tensor products. My ideal answer would be some kind of explanation of that in more elementary language. Maybe your proof is exactly what he means but I am not sure. Anyway, thanks for the effect, your proof helped a bit.